# How to use async in Global teardown in Jest with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, jestjs, ts-jest

What I'm trying is to use `async` in `globalTeardown` in Jest with TypeScript.

My `jest.config.js` is...

```
module.exports = {
  preset: 'ts-jest',
  testEnvironment: 'node',
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ['<rootDir>/dist/', '<rootDir>/node_modules/'],
  globalSetup: '<rootDir>/tests/global-setup.ts',
  globalTeardown: '<rootDir>/tests/global-teardown.ts',
};
```

`<rootDir>/tests/global-teardown.ts` is...

```
require('ts-node/register');
import { redisClient } from "../config/session";

export default async () => {
  await redisClient.quit();
  console.log('Exiting test...');
  process.exit();
};
```

This causes the following error:

> Error: Jest: Got error running globalTeardown - /ROOT_OF_APP/tests/global-teardown.ts, reason: [TSError: tests/global-teardown.ts:26:111 - error TS2322: Type 'number' is not assignable to type '{ label: number; sent: () => any; trys: never[]; ops: never[]; }'.

If I remove `async` and `await redisClient.quit()`, the error doesn't occur. So, I feel that Jest with TypeScript can't use `async` for ***global teardown***.

However, I'm actually using `async` in ***global setup*** without seeing any error.

Here's the global set up file

```
require('ts-node/register');
// imported modules here...

export default async () => {
  await someAsyncFunction();
};
```

My tsconfig.json is...

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": ["es2020"],
    "module": "commonjs",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "outDir": "./dist",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "typeRoots": ["./node_modules/@types", "./typings"]
  },
  "include": ["**/*.ts"]
}
```

Do you see why ***global teardown*** can't use `async` (while ***global setup*** can)? Any advice will be appreciated!

Comment: It looks like the error is elsewhere. There is no problem in using async global teardown. Can you share the stack trace of the error?